# Harnack's Inequality and (hypo)elliptic PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Background: I am aware of the Harnack's Inequality for linear elliptic equations.

My questions are:

(a) Is there a version of Harnack's Inequality for nonlinear elliptic equations, say, of the form $$Lu = |u|^pu ?$$
where $L$ is elliptic? 
Edit: This I understand now. Please look at (b) and (c). I am leaving this for the sake of "completeness"...

(b) How about the same question (I am actually more interested in this) when $L$ is hypoelliptic?

(c) Suppose I have a non-negative solution to the equation $Lu = |u|^pu $, with $L$ being elliptic/hypoelliptic. I want to show that the solution is actually positive. What other generic method is there to proceed other than Harnack's Inequality? I realise this last question is kind of vague, but I hope the intent behind the question is clear.

Comment: For (c) you don't need a Harnack inequality, you can use the *strict maximum principle*

Comment: @Robert Haslhofer Is there a maximum principle for hypoelliptic operators? Can you please point me to a source? Thanks!

Comment: @grateful: No there is no maximum principle in general. Maximum principle is valid only for second order operators.